# ERROR: Cannot find module '../node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, ghost-blog

There is a production version of Ghost blogging platform with content and style changes on our server. I downloaded the blog's app folder to my local machine. The instructions seem straight forward.

Quickstart:

1. `npm install -g grunt-cli`
2. `npm install`
3. `grunt init` (and `grunt prod` if you want to run Ghost in production mode)
4. `npm start`

But when I run `grunt init` I get the following:

```
Running "shell:bower" (shell) task

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'q'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/steelcollar/workspace/blog/node_modules/.bin/bower:6:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
Warning: Command failed:
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'q'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/steelcollar/workspace/blog/node_modules/.bin/bower:6:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
Use --force to continue.
```

Eventually, running `npm start` leads to:

`ERROR: Cannot find module '../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'`

I have bower and grunt installed. I haven't changed the code at all. Where could the problem be?

*Update:*

According to the folder structure I downloaded, the path is `../node-v11-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'` instead of `../node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'`.

I am receiving this error if I change the folder name from `darwin` to `linux` though:

```
ERROR: dlopen(../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
../node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

Comment: Are you running this on Linux or OSX?

Comment: I am running this on OSX.

Comment: It sounds like for some reason, it installed and compiled the binary for Linux instead of OSX. I have no idea why it would have done that though.

Answer (score 6):

Hi I had the same situation and this is how I solved it:

On the local computer, simply `npm uninstall sqlite3` and `npm install sqlite3 --save`, and it should work normally now.

I'm not sure why it's like this. But I think it's because the versions of sqlite3 each OS requires are different, simply downloading the app directory from server to local computer will result in incompatibility issue, so just let npm decide which version of sqlite3 to install.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. This didn't work:

```
yarn remove sqlite3 && yarn add sqlite3
```

Then I tried this, which did:

```
npm uninstall sqlite3 && npm install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this would be to run `npm rebuild`. This will rebuild all the bindings relevant to the current project, especially after updates.

Comment: this is the smart answer